# how to unpickle a file in python?

Tags: python, pickle

For example i have two dictionaries 
this is what I have tried:

```
def unpickle(filename):
    open = open(filename, "rb")
    Dic1 = cPickle.load(open)
    Dic2 = cPickle.load(open)
    open.close()
    return Dic1,Dict2
```

But it gives an error when I want to unpickle in another function.
It says **invalid load key,'m'**

Comment: How are you invoking it from another function? What's the error you get?

Comment: *it is not working* is **not** a problem description we can help you with. Please do tell us what is going wrong. What happened, what error messages did you get if any and what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: It says invalid load key

Comment: Perhaps a snippet showing how you're writing to the file with some example data would help

Comment: please show your ENTIRE function that you are calling and the traceback error! original code is very helpful, because the issue is probably somewhere else

Answer (score 3):

Ahhh so what is happening is that you open the file once and close it once, but use it twice. I took my own unpickle function and tried creating two things and it gave me an error.

this is the error I get when using your previous function:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in pickleLoad
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

but when I edited it as such, then it worked fine:

```
import cPickle
def unpickle(filename):
    open_first = open(filename, "rb")
    Dic1 = cPickle.load(open_first)
    open_again = open(filename, "rb")
    Dic2 = cPickle.load(open_again)
    open_first.close()
    open_again.close()
    return Dic1,Dic2
```

But your function returns the same content in two variables since we only have one argument namely `filename`.. to just unpickle a file:

```
def unpickle(filename):
    f = open(filename, "rb")
    d = cPickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    return d
```

Comment: Assuming the OP didn't just write two consecutive objects out to the file, yes. But the marshalled format allows you to just keep writing pickled objects to the file

Comment: hmmmm well then maybe this fixes it for some other reason...and @ErikaSawajiri: if this does work please upvote and mark it as correct so people know that this is the acceptable solution

Comment: It still doesn't work :(

Comment: well I did have to assume your error since you didn't post it...could you please post your error...also, please show the input you are giving to your function!

Comment: It's a 185 lines codes and I can't copy all of the codes since it is an assignment. so, if I uploaded there will be a turnitin to check plagiarism :(

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion anyway.. I will try to figure it out :)

Comment: if it's an assignment you should tag it `homework`. If you post the traceback error and just explain what you're input is, it could make this possible

Comment: Actually I have to make a histogram function that stipulating the name of a pickle file that contains an information

Comment: That code can't run. The builtin `open` is shadowed by a variable with the same name. The second `open` will raise an error.

Comment: for my function? that function runs normally for me

Comment: If you write `open = open(filename, "rb")` then `open` changes from <type 'builtin_function_or_method'> to  <type 'file'>.

Comment: right, that was an original mistake on my part, I ran the code in my own function and copied and pasted the OPs, which had that error...fixed